# thumbnail screenshot of webpages with Perl :: Mechanize

Tags: perl, parsing, mechanize, thumbnails

i use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to control a firefox instance and dump the rendered page with $mech->content_as_png.

**New update**: see at the end of the initial posting: 
thanks to user1126070 we have a new solution - which i want to try out later the day [right now  i am in office and not at home - in front of the machine with the programme ]

```
$mech->repl->repl->setup_client( { extra_client_args => { timeout => 5*60 } } );
```

i try out the version that `put links to @list and use eval` and do the following:

```
while (scalar(@list)) {
        my $link = pop(@list);
        print "trying $link\n";
        eval{
        $mech->get($link);
        sleep (5);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(OUTPUT, ">$name");
        print OUTPUT $png;        
        close(OUTPUT);
        }
        if ($@){
          print "link: $link failed\n";
          push(@list,$link);#put the end of the list
          next;
        }
        print "$link is done!\n";

}
```

**BTW:** user1126070 what with the trimming down the images to thumbnail-size. Should i use imager here. Can you suggest some solution thing here...!? That would be great.

**end of Update**

Here the problem-outline continues - as written at the very **beginning of this Q & A**

**problem-outline:** I have a list of 2500 websites and need to grab a thumbnail screenshot of them. How do I do that? I could try to parse the sites either with Perl.- Mechanize would be a good thing. Note: i only need the results as a thumbnails that are a maximum 240 pixels in the long dimension. At the moment i have a solution which is slow and does not give back thumbnails: How to make the script running faster with less overhead - spiting out the thumbnails

But i have to be aware that setting it up can pose quite a challenge, though.
If all works as expected, you can simply use a script like this to dump images of the desired websites, but you should start Firefox and resize it to the desired width manually (height doesn't matter, WWW::Mechanize::Firefox always dumps the whole page).

What i have **done so far** is alot - i work with mozrepl. At the moment i struggle with timeouts: Is there a way to specify Net::Telnet timeout with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?
At the moment my internet connection is very slow and sometimes I get error

```
with $mech->get():
command timed-out at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Client.pm line 186
```

SEE THIS ONE:

```
> $mech->repl->repl->timeout(100000);
```

Unfortunatly it does not work: Can't locate object method "timeout" via package "MozRepl"
Documentation says this should:

```
$mech->repl->repl->setup_client( { extra_client_args => { timeout => 1 +80 } } );
```

What i have tried allready; here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open(INPUT, "<urls.txt") or die $!;

while (<INPUT>) {
        chomp;
        print "$_\n";
        $mech->get($_);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(OUTPUT, ">$name");
        print OUTPUT $png;
        sleep (5);
}
```

Well this does not care about the size: See the output commandline:

```
linux-vi17:/home/martin/perl # perl mecha_test_1.pl
www.google.com
www.cnn.com
www.msnbc.com
command timed-out at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Client.pm line 186
linux-vi17:/home/martin/perl #
```

And here - this is my source: see a snippet-example of the sites i have in the url-list.

urls.txt  - the list of sources

```
www.google.com
www.cnn.com
www.msnbc.com
news.bbc.co.uk
www.bing.com
www.yahoo.com and so on...
```

**BTW:** With that many url's we have to expect that some will fail and handle that. For example, we put the failed ones in an array or hash and retry them X times.

UTSL

well how is this one here...

```
 sub content_as_png {

my ($self, $tab, $rect) = @_;
$tab ||= $self->tab;
$rect ||= {};

# Mostly taken from
# http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/interactor-screenshot-server
my $screenshot = $self->repl->declare(<<'JS');
function (tab,rect) {
    var browser = tab.linkedBrowser;
    var browserWindow = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
        .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
    var win = browser.contentWindow;
    var body = win.document.body;
    if(!body) {
        return;
    };
    var canvas = browserWindow
           .document
           .createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
    var left = rect.left || 0;
    var top = rect.top || 0;
    var width = rect.width || body.clientWidth;
    var height = rect.height || body.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(1.0, 1.0);
    ctx.drawWindow(win, left, top, width, height, 'rgb(255,255,255)');
    ctx.restore();

    //return atob(
    return canvas
           .toDataURL('image/png', '')
           .split(',')[1]
    // );
}
JS
    my $scr = $screenshot->($tab, $rect);
    return $scr ? decode_base64($scr) : undef
};
```

Love to hear from you! 
greetings zero

Comment: Just FYI, these slides on how to control WebKit with perl might be of interest as well: http://potyl.github.com/Talk-WebKit-Perl/  and his code, such as screenshot.pl: https://github.com/potyl/Webkit/blob/master/screenshot.pl .   Haven't tried it, but it looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried this out? It is working?

```
$mech->repl->repl->setup_client( { extra_client_args => { timeout => 5*60 } } );
```

put links to @list and use eval

```
while (scalar(@list)) {
        my $link = pop(@list);
        print "trying $link\n";
        eval{
        $mech->get($link);
        sleep (5);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(OUTPUT, ">$name");
        print OUTPUT $png;        
        close(OUTPUT);
        }
        if ($@){
          print "link: $link failed\n";
          push(@list,$link);#put the end of the list
          next;
        }
        print "$link is done!\n";

}
```

Comment: thx user1126070!!! that looks great. I have put your ideas to the **top** of the **initial-posting**. 

i set this to `$mech->repl->repl->setup_client( { extra_client_args => { timeout => 5*60 } } );`

And: i want to try out later the day [right now i am in office and not at home - in front of the machine with the programme ] **BTW**, what with the trimming down the images to thumbnail-size. Should i use **imager** here. Can you suggest some **ideas and line**s here...!? That would be great.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks - i check it out! I come back and report all  the  findings. thx again